# Why is it useful to pass a class to a method in Java?

Tags: java

This hasn't been covered in my course and I am having trouble thinking up a reason why would I want this. I've come across the code below:

```
OpenNetworking proxy = service.getPort(OpenNetworking.class);
```

In the above line I can see that it is returning the port and it is passing the class to the method but I read this as the `OpenNetworking.class` isn't instantiated yet. I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with C#?

Comment: The example I gave is from Java, I just thought the same operation can be done in C#. Apologies for my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of a [Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern.

The class type is provided to the service to give a `Port` on the specified type `OpenNetworking`.

A class type, in this case, is handy as it is a simplest way to provide a unique identifier to an object when doing object creation. It doesn't need to be maintained, should the state of the object changes as the `class` contains the type of the object.

Answer (score 2):

There can be many reasons to do that:

> 1. Controlling number of instances of a class: Say you want to control how many instances you want for a class, you can make constructor
>      private or package level and return same instance when somebody calls
>      your method
> 2. Security: You might want your class to be secure and generally don't want to allow anybody to instantiate your class.
> 3. Dependency: Your class might have dependency which can be figured out only at runtime and then service class use reflection to
>      instantiate class appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Here we are passing the class type (Class in Java). So the treatment in the method getPort is done based on the Type of Class, we don't need an Object instance to handle it.
It is different, of course, than this code (whic doesn't compile):

```
OpenNetworking proxy = service.getPort(new OpenNetworking());
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the method `service.getPort();` behaves according to the type in the parameter, imagin that there is a port for openNetworking and another one for closeNetworking, so providing the class name as a parameter would be enough to get the needed port number, one can create an enumeration for that but then extending existing code would force you to extend your enumeration too for each type.

Answer (score 0):

Also because of limitations of generics, when you have a generic class/method and you need to create a new instance, you will need a class. For example:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    public static<T> T create() {
        return new T(); // will not work
    }

    public static<T> T create(Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.newInstance(); //will work
    }
}
```

so you need class instance to create a new object of that type.

Answer (score 0):

The used method has this definition:

```
public <T> T getPort(Class<T> serviceEndpointInterface)
```

So it returns an instance of an object which extends the class T (a proxy,synthetic class instance)